# Standalone XML-RPC/SOAP/etc implementation for Java

Tags: java, soap, xml-rpc

Could anybody give me a hint if any standalone XML-RPC implementation for Java exists?

Under "standalone" I mean library which is not depends on any transport implementation and/or servlet container.

Ideal solution should be like [json-rpc base](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/json-rpc-2.0-base.html), so it should allow to register any instance of any class as invokation target, then parse any string/byte array and invoke appropriate methods.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Apache XML-RPC](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/) or [Delight](http://delight.opendfki.de/)

Comment: Both of them are dependant of transport layer. Both of them are designed to work over HTTP. Same for Spring Webservices, Apache CXF, Apache AXIS/AXIS2.